combinations of preview environment and ert environment doesn't work in LyX 2.4.2?
Just recently I've upgraded my laptop and downloaded the newest version of lyx (2.4.2).
I've had a similar problem on my old laptop when I upgraded from version 2.3.8 to 2.4, then the solution (which was in this post I created back then) was installing the packages bigfoot.sty (which contains suffix.sty) and cprotect.sty and it solved the problem back then, but now it this fix doesn't work anymore.
to explain the problem in detail; in LyX I like to surround the ERT environment (big red text or just TeX code however you prefer calling it) in the preview environment to render my code (for plots and such) in the LyX file itself, the problem now is that it does nothing, it just stays like this as if the preview environment doesn't even work (to be clear the compiled file is rendered just as expected so the code is not the problem, and it doesn't throw any errors)
in the image, you can see that the preview environment surrounds the ERT but it doesn't render: 
my preamble is the following: (the beginning is automatic because I use Hebrew, everything after the comment is from me)
\def\@spart#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \if@RTL\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\huge \bfseries #1\par}%
\nobreak
\vskip 3ex
\@afterheading}
% Added by lyx2lyx
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xstring}

if someone might know of the fix or some way to follow the updated requirements for the instant preview to work in lyx I would greatly appreciate it. (some official website that mentions it or if it's in the change logs and I missed it)
